# Facing stored procedure related issue like Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

Here is my stored procedure and in Status='2' I get an error for conversion and here I am trying to find last week data including today. I will be grateful if anybody can help me with this.

Here is screenshot of error I get :

[Error facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCDF1.png)

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint]
    @RequestNo VARCHAR(50),
    @FromDate varchar(50),
    @ToDate varchar(50),
    @Status varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(8000)

DECLARE @CurrentDate  Varchar(100) =GETDATE()

IF (@RequestNo IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    BEGIN     
        SET @SQLStr = 'SELECT Id,RequestStatus, RequestNo,RequestDate From CYGNUX_Request_Header WHERE RequestNo='+''''+@RequestNo+'''';
    END
END
ELSE      
IF @Status = '1'
BEGIN
    SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus,RequestDate,RequestNo from CYGNUX_Request_Header where RequestDate between '+CHAR(39)+  convert(varchar(50) , @FromDate)  +CHAR(39)+ ' AND '+CHAR(39)+ convert(varchar(50), @ToDate) +CHAR(39);
END
IF @Status ='2'
BEGIN
        SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus, RequestNo, RequestDate from CYGNUX_Request_Header where RequestDate>='+(DATEADD(day,-11117,GETDATE()));
END
IF @Status ='3'
BEGIN
            SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus,RequestNo, RequestDate As Today from CYGNUX_Request_Header Where RequestDate='+CHAR(39)+  convert(varchar(50) , @CurrentDate)  +CHAR(39) ;
END
IF @Status ='4'
BEGIN
                SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus, RequestNo,RequestDate  from CYGNUX_Request_Header WHERE RequestDate<=' +CHAR(39)+  convert(varchar(50) , @CurrentDate)  +CHAR(39);
END 

PRINT @SQLStr;

EXEC(@SQLStr);


END
```

Comment: Stop passing and manipulating dates as strings.  This is a very undesirable practice because it virtually guarantees that you will constantly be running into problems just like this.  If you have to receive your date parameters as strings from client programs, then convert them into Dates/Times immediately.  Then at least you will know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you can find the right T-SQL

```
IF @Status ='2'
BEGIN
     SET @SQLStr = '
             SELECT Id,RequestStatus, RequestNo, RequestDate 
             FROM CYGNUX_Request_Header 
             WHERE RequestDate>='+CAST(DATEADD(day,-11117,GETDATE()) AS varchar(50))
END
```

Comment: Was the solution helpful in solving your problem? Let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

In the `if @status = 2` condition, the expression `(DATEADD(day,-11117,GETDATE()))` returns a value of type `datetime`. You are trying to concatenate that onto the end of a string using the `+` operator. You can't do that:

```
select 'my character value' + getdate() -- << fails
select 'my character value' + convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) -- OK
```

This will fix your specific error, but your code has a lot of room for improvement in other areas as well. If you have a colleague with more SQL experience, see if they can give you some pointers.